# How to delete all telephone numbers having prefix 913- in a txt file

Tags: powershell

How to delete all telephone numbers in a large file  having prefix 913- in a text file

For example in my text file the content has the following 
xylem 1  ......  913-12346 med 3  913-33346

### dpt 7d ------913-12347   mod 8r  913-44448

---

and so on

i want to delete only the 913-44448,913-12347,913-33346 ,913-12346

Comment: What is the format of the text file?

Comment: its a messy .txt file having thousands of  name and telephone numbers

Comment: The data is largely unstructured and messy  text.  my task is to remove all the telephone numbers

Comment: Could you use Python or something like that?

Comment: i would prefer Powershell if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerShell you can do this:

```
(Get-Content -Path 'INPUT PATH AND FILENAME' -Raw) -replace '913-\d+' | Set-Content -Path  'OUTPUT PATH AND FILENAME'
```

leaving you with another messy text file:

> ```
> xylem 1 ......  med 3 
> dpt 7d ------ mod 8r
> ```

Comment: Thanks a ton  Matthew and Coocol for your help.You guys rock. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
awk '{gsub(/913-[0-9]+/, "")}1' input.txt
```

Comment: it looks like python code, will try and let you know

Comment: @SarangihelloMrityunjaya it's not Python. `awk` is a linux command.

Comment: `awk` is a text processing tool installed on most Unix-like operating systems like Linux and macOS. `gsub` is awk's built-in function which means replacing all text found by the regular expression `913-[0-9]+` with empty string `""`